# Redux and firebase passing reacthooks

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

My problem here is I'm trying to collect the data in react hooks and then I want to pass it in my initial state of redux which can be shown like this:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { doc, onSnapshot, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { db } from '../lib/firebase'
import { itemsCollectionRef } from '../lib/firebase-collection'


function Items(params) {
    const [UsersData,setUsersData] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(itemsCollectionRef,snapshot => {
            setUsersData(snapshot.docs.map((doc,idx) => {
                return {
                    ...doc.data(),
                    name:doc.data().name
                }
            }))
        })
        return () => {
            unsubscribe()
        }
    },[])

    return UsersData
}
//Here I'm trying to pass all the data in firebase in the itemsSlice

export const itemsSlice = createSlice({
    name:"items",
    initialState:{ value: Items },
    reducers:{
        addItem: (state,action) => {
            state.value.push(action.payload)
            const { id,name,message,shape } = action.payload

            setDoc(doc(db,`items`,`${action.payload.name}-${id}`),{
              name:name,message:message,shape:shape
            })
            .then( res => {})
            .catch(err => {})

        },
        ...

    }
})
```

So as you see I'm trying to pass my `Usersdata` in the `itemsSlice` but the thing is that my `Items` function is passing all the format of code which is kind of wrong. It supposed to pass the array `UsersData` what did I miss here? Can anyone help me? thanks :)

Comment: The initial state is set right away, when this file loads. There isn't a way to have the firestore data already in hand, so the only sensible initial state is an empty array. When you eventually load data, you can dispatch an action to update the state.

Comment: Can you give me an example or a solution at it? I don't get what you're talking about sorry.

Comment: For the initial state, do `initialState:{ value: []}`. Do you know how to dispatch actions? If so, add another action, perhaps called `setItems`, with a reducer to update that value array. When you load the data, dispatch that action.

Comment: Oh no no..what I mean is just exporting my UsersData in firebase and pass it in the initialState not doing a dispatch cause I already get the dispatch action the only problem is getting the new usersdata that will record in the firebase store

Comment: Can you please show an example? I really don't get it... I just want to pass the values of firebase store in the initial state so I won't be calling a lot in firebase store.

Comment: The initial state is set synchronously. It will take time to fetch data from firestore, so you cannot put firestore data in the initial state.

Comment: So how I will do that? But I already called a return UsersData so that it will pass in initialState..I  really don't get it hahaha...

Comment: Although I can do it by just calling the onSnapshot in other react hooks but I really want just to pass it in initialState so I won't have to repeat calling the same onSnapshot in each files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to dispatch an action to populate the`items` state *after* the app/component has mounted and rendered and then run the `useEffect` hook to make the asynchronous documents request. For this you'll need to provide valid initial state for the slice, and add a new case reducer to initialize the state to a specific value.

```
const initialState = { value: [] };

export const itemsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "items",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    initialize: (_, action) => ({
      state.value = action.payload;
    }),
    ...
  }
});
```

Next will be *some* `useEffect` hook that makes the firebase call to get the documents and dispatches an action to initialize the `items` state. The reason I say *some* `useEffect` hook is because it seems `Items` is defined like it's a custom hook, but it's not called like a React hook.

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import itemsSlice from '../items.slice';

...

const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(itemsCollectionRef, snapshot => {
    const userData = snapshot.docs.map((doc, idx) => ({
      ...doc.data(),
      name: doc.data().name
    }));
    dispatch(itemsSlice.initialize(userData));
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

The above logic *could* be abstracted into a custom hook and then ***imported and called*** from a React function component.